# Bernoulli numbers, primes, integers and the Möbius function

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, analytic-number-theory, mobius-inversion, cauchy-product

For $|\frac{x}{2\pi}|<1$ using Möbius inversion for the Taylor series of the logarithm one deduces $$\frac{x}{2\pi}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{n}\log\left(1-\frac{x^n}{(2\pi)^n}\right)$$ thus $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{kn}\frac{x^{nk}}{(2\pi)^{nk}}=\frac{1}{2\pi}(e^x-1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k x^k}{k!},$$ where we've used the series expansion $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers.

Using Cauchy products in RHS I believe that it's possible deduce the following

> **Claim 1.** For $|x|<2\pi$ $$\frac{1}{2\pi}(e^x-1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{B_k x^k}{k!}=\frac{x}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{\binom {n} {k}}B_{n-k}\right)x^n.$$

Equating RHS of previous claim with LHS of our first deduction one has

> **(Wrong) Claim 2.** For every composite integer $n\geq 2$ $$\sum_{\substack{a,b\geq 1}\\a\cdot b=n}\frac{\mu\left(\frac{n}{b}\right)}{n(2\pi)^n}=\frac{1}{2\pi}\left(\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{\binom {n} {k}}B_{n-k}\right).$$

I am saying that this Claim 2 is wrong, the corresponding (correct) claim for prime numbers is:

If $n$ is prime then $$\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{\binom {n} {k}}B_{n-k}=0.$$

> **Question.** I would like to know the right claim for composite numbers. **Many thanks.**

Comment: The claim for prime numbers is wrong. Take $n=5$ for example.

Comment: Then I am sorry, my thoughts were do the specialisation to get the case of prime number. Many thanks @MarcoCantarini

Comment: Where are you stuck ?

Comment: I would like to know if it is feasible/possible deduce relationships equating $x^{t}$ from both sides of $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(n)}{kn}\frac{x^{nk}}{(2\pi)^{nk}}=\frac{x}{2\pi}+\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=2}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n!}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{n!}{\binom {n} {k}}B_{n-k}\right)x^n.$$ Many thanks @user1952009

Comment: @user1952009 I've an infinite series, a double series as LHS, and I would like to know if it is possible deduce some recurrence between the Möbius function and Bernoulli numbers from this identity equating the coefficient of $x^t$ in LHS with the coefficient of $x^t$ in RHS. It's possible? Does make sense the question? Add an answer if you are interesting with your calculations or discussion/reasoning.

Comment: Why do you think this equality of double $\sum$ is true ? Can you show it rigorously ? for what $x$ ? And then where are you stuck ? (*écris tous les détails, aussi rigoureusement qu possible, car sinon ça nous oblige à t'écrire une démonstration complète ou juste quelques 'hint' qui forcément ne seront pas adaptés à ton niveau, et tu n'apprendras rien*

Comment: Many thanks for your words in french language, I believe that the identity is right by absolute convergence for $|x|<2\pi$. But if there is some mistakes you can add an answer with those @user1952009

Comment: The idea is write each side as a simple infinite series, and from those see if my question is well possed @user1952009

Comment: I don't accept "I believe that", or you know how to prove everything rigorously, or you are stuck somewhere. At 1st you need to prove that there is a $r > 0$ such that for $|z| < r$ : $f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{k!} z^k$ where $B_k = f^{(k)}(0)$ are some (real) numbers that we don't really care about, except that $\frac{B_k}{k!} = \mathcal{O}(r^{-k})$ so that the power series converges and is analytic on $|z| < r$

Comment: You are right because mathematics are $100$% certainty, but I don't know  if my question is right and are feasible the identities that I evoke @user1952009 , thanks for your proof of the generating function of Bernouli numbers.